# Sitecore 7.5 ContentSearchManager (CD environment) index is empty when visiting from one hostname, but populated when from another

Tags: lucene, sitecore, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am having an unusual issue with my search indexes and ContentSearchManager in sitecore 7.5 when deployed on a CD.

if I use one hostname it is populated, but with another hostname its empty.

I have checked the siteconfig and both hostnames is in the hostname list, and the site responds to both, but my search indexes keeps showing up empty on the one and populated on the other.

Any help is much appreciated.

if you need to see configs and implementations, I can show you, but I am not entirely sure what you exactly need, so tell me, and I will show.

Many thanks

Comment: 1. Are you 100% sure you're hitting the same server with both requests? No entry in hosts file for one of them? Are you sure your hitting the same IIS site on that server? 2. Do you use default Sitecore index or custom one (what do you pass to `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex()` method)? Do you have multiple site definition or just a single `website` site? Do all your site definition user `web` database?

Comment: I agree with Marek. The index call is knows nothing about your site configuration. Coming from a different URL would have no effect unless you have added something about the sitename to your Search Context call.

Comment: Yes I am sure its the same server, but I have found the the culprit, apparently it was my [OutputCache] attribute that was causing it.

Comment: I am now facing a new problem, my indexes on the CD isn't refreshed when CM is publishing, and it is being notoriously difficult to find the cause.

Comment: @RobinOvergaard What indexing strategy are you using? On CD server you should always enable both "onPublishEndAsync" and "remoteRebuild" on your "web" indexes

Comment: @AhmedOkour okay thanks for the advice :), would that be fine to setup in all my web indexes on the CM as well, or what should that instance use ?

Comment: @RobinOvergaard CM usually use "onPublishEndAsync" strategy for "web" indexes, no need for "remoteRebuild" strategy on CM